# How can you use a background image that does not cover form fields?

Tags: html, css, forms, background-image

I have one page with several sections.
On one of the section is a contact form.

```html
<div class="watermark">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>... here is a form</section>
</div>
```

The page has a picture as a background, like a watermark.
i have add it using the following css

```
.watermark::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(my_watermark.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.1;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-size: 50%;
    position: fixed;
  }
```

The problem now is that the watermark blocks the fields in the form so that it is only possible to click in the field on the left side.

if I try to click into the field on the right side of a field, it is "blocked"

here is an live example: https://jsbin.com/xomowakuvi/edit?html,css,output

How can it be fixed?
background image should be visible on each section when scrolling. that's why I used `position: fixed`

Comment: pointer-events:none on the pseudo element

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, it was not easy to look for it, because i don't know exactly how to describe the problem. :) I have now solved it using `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with layering. Simply set a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) of `-1` on your `::after` to position it 'behind' your content, thus allowing your content to be selected instead of your watermark:

```
.watermark::after {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: it looks like what i was looking for. Thank you